# How to call a function inside a component in a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I have a component which has a function in it. also I have a custom hook name "useHook-A" I want to call my function which is inside the component through my hook "A". I dont know how to call that function. I cant export it and I cant pass it as props.

```
const MyComponent = () =>{
   const myFunction = () =>{}
}
export default Mycomponent

const useHook-A = () =>{

  // Here I want to call myFunction which is inside the MyComponent
}
export default useHook-A
```

Comment: please show code ... words are always difficult to understand what is going on, try attaching a reproducible sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass your function as a parameter of your hook:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const myFunction = () => {};
  useHook-A(myFunction);
}
```

```js
const useHook-A = (func) => {
  // func();
}
```

Comment: my mistake was that I was calling my function inside my hook as props.func . thanks